# sx prop not getting transformed in custom components in Material-UI 5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, create-react-app

Could not find any related question in StackOverflow.

So, in box component, `sx` prop is getting transformed, say from

```
<Box
  sx={{
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    height: '100%'
  }}
>
```

to

```
<div class="MuiBox-root MuiBox-root-371"/>
```

but its not transforming in other components like `ListSubheader`

```
<ListSubheader
  disableGutters
  disableSticky
  sx={{
    color: 'text.primary',
    fontSize: '0.75rem',
    lineHeight: 2.5,
    fontWeight: 700,
    textTransform: 'uppercase'
  }}
>
```

is transforming to

```
<li class="MuiListSubheader-root" sx="[object Object]">Manage</li>
```

I am using create-react-app with Material-UI 5, this is my package.json

[image: this is my package.json]

For some reason, my `sx` prop is not getting transformed to a class name. a screenshot of that

[image: a screenshot of that]

Any hints what configuration might be incorrect? Not sure, what all information to provide.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check your component code, you might import the v4 component:

```
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
```

In v5, MUI components are moved to a new package called `@mui/material`

```
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
```

You can only use `sx` in other components without configuration in **MUI v5**, if you're using v4 or the older beta versions of the v5, you have to create a wrapper component as explained from this [section](https://v4.mui.com/system/basics/#sx-property):

```
import {
  compose,
  spacing,
  palette,
  styleFunctionSx
} from "@material-ui/system";
import MuiListSubheader from "@material-ui/core/ListSubheader";

const styleFunction = styleFunctionSx(compose(spacing, palette));
const ListSubheader = styled(MuiListSubheader)(styleFunction);
```

```
<ListSubheader sx={...} />
```

In v5, you can use `sx` directly from the components since they've been [migrated to `emotion`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/24405).

[image: Edit 69243066/sx-prop-not-getting-transformed-in-custom-componsnts-in-material-ui-5]